# Carlsen vs Karjakin individual encounter results statistics so far?

Tags: statistics, world-championship

I wonder how many times Carlsen and Karjakin played so far and who won the more number of games. Any idea?

Answer (score 6):

There is a list of chess games between them [here](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/ezsearch.pl?search=Magnus+Carlsen+vs+Sergey+Karjakin); I'm not sure if any games are missing. The list includes blitz, rapid and blindfold games, but there's a convenient statistics block at the top of the page:

> #### LIFETIME RECORD:
>
> Classical games: Magnus Carlsen beat Sergey Karjakin 4 to 1, with 17 draws.
>   Including rapid/exhibition games: Magnus Carlsen beat Sergey Karjakin 18 to 8, with 22 draws.
>   Only rapid/exhibition games: Magnus Carlsen beat Sergey Karjakin 14 to 7, with 5 draws.